# How does the initialblockdownload field in the getblockchaininfo RPC work?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, synchronization

Let's say I have a fully synced node that returns `"initialblockdownload": false`. If I turn it off, will it show `"initialblockdownload": true` when I start the node again? In other words, if initialblockdownload is false, will it be set to true again if the node needs to resync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `initialblockdownload` field in the output of the `getblockchaininfo` RPC reports the internal "IsInitialBlockDownload" state of the node software.

The value of this state is always `true` at startup, and latches to `false` whenever both of these conditions are true:

- The currently active chain has at least as much cumulative PoW as the hardcoded constant in the software (updated every major release).
- The timestamp of the currently active tip is no more than 24 hours in the past.

Whenever the IsInitialBlockDownload state latches to `false`, it never reverts to `true` (unless restarted).

Comment: What would happen if your node was running but had no connection to another node? Wouldn’t it revert to `initialblockdownload: false` after 24h?

Comment: @Murch No, it never reverts to `false` unless restarted (as of Bitcoin Core 26.x). I don't think there would be anything wrong with reverting in such a scenario, but I also don't think it adds much.

Comment: This one-way behavior also has the advantage that once `initialblockdownload` becomes `false` (actually, `ChainstateManager::m_cached_finished_ibd` becomes `true`), this state can be reported to other software without locking `cs_main`. This improves system performance, since this state is queried often.